# Activity being created twice on android

Tags: java, android

First of all, I'm new to Android Development so please have patience with me.

I'll start from the UI, I have a button that once you tap it, starts an activity for a result.

```
public class GUIActivity extends Activity

    @Override
    public void onClick(....){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("action", FROM_CAMERA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Log(TAG, "onActivityResult");
        //handle result
    }

}
```

The `GetImageActivity` class is a wrapper for two other activities, one to capture an image from the camera and other to get it from the gallery. It returns and Uri object of the selected image.

```
public class GetImageActivity extends Activity{
    private Uri mediaUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int action =  extras.getInt("action");

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        switch(action){
            case FROM_CAMERA:
                mediaUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(....));
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mediaUri);

                Log.d(TAG, "Calling camera activity"
                startActivityForResult(intent, action);
                break;
            case FROM GALLERY:
                //...
        }            
    }

    @Override
    onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");

        switch(requestCode){
            case FROM_CAMERA:
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtra("uri", mediaUri);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera activity failed!");
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                    finish();
                }
                break;

            case FROM_GALLERY:
                //...

        }
    }
}
```

This is what is expected to happen when the user clicks on the button:

- The camera activity should start.
- Once the user takes a picture it should send back its URI to the GUI class.

Sometimes (it's usually a 50% chance) it works at expected, but other times this is what happens:

- The camera activity starts.
- The user takes a picture.
- The camera activity starts AGAIN.
- The user can either take another picture or go back.
- Either case, the URI that gets back to the GUI class does not exist.

I've added a couple of debug log lines to follow the sequence of events. When I get the bad behaviour this is the output I get:

- GetImageActivity - onCreate
- GetImageActivity - Calling Camera Activity

The camera opens, and once I've taken a picture it says:

- GetImageActivity - onCreate (again)
- GetImageActivity - Calling Camera Activity
- GetImageActivity - onActivityResult

The camera opens for the second time. The user takes another picture and:

- GetImageActivity - onActivityResult
- GUIActivity - onActivityResult

So my question is... what could cause the `GetImageActivity` to be called twice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is improper handling of the `Activity` lifecycle.

The second call to `onCreate` is for handling the result.

Android may choose to destroy an `Activity` that is waiting for the call to `onActivityResult`; especially when free memory is running low.  Some devices appear more aggressive about destroying Activitys that are on the task stack.   I can reliably recreate the issue on a Samsung device set to a debugging mode called "strict mode".

You can verify whether this is your issue by logging calls to `onCreate` & `onDestroy`.

In the case of a destroyed activity, when the activity result needs to be processed, Android will recreate the `Activity`, passing a `savedInstanceState` to `onCreate`.  So, the remedy is to check the value of `savedInstanceState` in your `GetImageActivity.onCreate`.   If it is not `null` then don't make any calls to `startActivity` because your `Activity` is being recreated to call `onActivityResult`.

Optionally, if you need to preserve any state then override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and put data you need into `outState`.

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your Activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode = "singleTask"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `startActivityForResult` it is telling Android that you want the result to be delivered to the `Activity` which is making that call. Which explains what you see when you logged `GetImageActivity - onCreate (again)`.

Since you call `startActivityForResult` in your *first* activity, that is, `GUIActivity` than you should be calling `setResult` in `GetImageActivity` to properly pass back the result.

So in `GetImageActivity.onActivityResult()` right before you call `finish()` you should call `setResult` so that when you return back to `GUIActivity` it can handle the expected result.

Comment: I'll edit the code to make it more clear. Where it says `//handle the result` on the `GetImageActivity` class, I actually do call `setResult()`. The thing to notice is that the activity is created again even before its `onActivityResult()` method gets called for the first time.