# Android - opening camera a second time

Tags: android, camera

This is the first time I post something here, so I apologize in advance for any mistake what-so-ever.

This is the situation:

I'm currently developing my first android app, sort of like a tracker:
1. log in
2. select weather, temperature etc
3. press the start button that activates a background GPS service and shows you a list of other attendees
4. click on an attendee and it shows you a timeline where you can add pictures etc.

Here is where the fun starts. When I open the camera it works most of the time, but once in a while the activity that opens the camera gets destroyed and when reopening (to further progress) it opens a second camera.

When I take a picture like that it completely ignores the first picture, restarts the gps-service, messes up my timeline and shows the login dialog when I go back to the the main activity (which is programmed to only show up when starting the app).

I have read an similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576238/activity-being-created-twice-on-android) and it might be the solution, but I can't get it to work.

The code for the camera activity:

```
public class AddPhotoActivity extends Activity {

private SharedPreferences savedValues;

private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private String imageName;

private int id;

private String startRideDateTime;
private SimpleDateFormat dateInSQL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
private Date date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_photo);

    savedValues = this.getSharedPreferences("SavedValues",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    id = savedValues.getInt("RideId", 0);
    startRideDateTime = savedValues.getString("StartRideDateTime", "");

    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(startRideDateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateInDir
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    startRideDateTime = dateInDir.format(date);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    savedValues = this.getSharedPreferences("SavedValues",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File storageDir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + „/app/„ + id + "/" + startRideDateTime + "/photos");
    storageDir.mkdirs();
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    imageName =  image.getName();

    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            addPhotoToDb();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
    } 
}

private void addPhotoToDb() {
    TimeLineDataSource timeLineDataSource = new TimeLineDataSource(this);
    timeLineDataSource.open();

    date = new Date();
    String dateString = dateInSQL.format(date);
    timeLineDataSource.createTimeLineItem(3, imageName, dateString);
    timeLineDataSource.close();

    finish();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
}
```

If anybody knows a solution to this I would be eternally grateful!

**Update:**

although I had better code after the previous suggestion it still didn't solve the problem. It seems that devices with less memory can get terminated at DVM-level, causing them to quit without onDestroy(). My issue is more or less resolved, but includes a lot of patchwork that I feel can be done in other, more efficient ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is what I usually use for taking a photo/picking a photo. I normally include the ability to pick a previous photo or take a new photo, and I don't run into this issue.

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
//zero can be replced with any action code to pick photo from gallery

Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
//one can be replced with any action code

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
        break; 
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, I agree with the solution from the other post, this in particular:

> In the case of a destroyed activity, when the activity result needs to
>   be processed, Android will recreate the Activity, passing a
>   savedInstanceState to onCreate. So, the remedy is to check the value
>   of savedInstanceState in your GetImageActivity.onCreate. If it is not
>   null then don't make any calls to startActivity because your Activity
>   is being recreated to call onActivityResult.
>
> Optionally, if you need to preserve any state then override
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and put data you need into
>   outState.

Comment: Thank you!

I actually restarted from scratch and used your code as the base for my activity.

The onDestroy-issues could probably be resolved one way or another, but I feel like your solution is simpler and more effective.

Comment: Update: although I had better code after the previous suggestion it still didn't solve the problem. It seems that devices with less memory can get terminated at DVM-level, causing them to quit without onDestroy(). My issue is more or less resolved, but includes a lot of patchwork that I feel can be done in other, more efficient ways.